# Rails redirect_to section of page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For a normal redirect it would be something like `redirect_to root_path`.

How would I redirect to something like: `localhost:3000/#contact`. Instead of just redirecting to root, i want to redirect to root but also to the contact section of the root page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
redirect_to root_path(anchor: 'contact')
```