# redirect to an anchor in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, anchor

I have been searching thru answers here for my problem but cant seem to find the exact fit. I am working on a blog and on each post you can vote if you like or dislike them. I am using act_as_votable for my voting table. The problem I am having is once you click on like or dislike you are redirected to the top of the page which gets annoying since you want to continue from where you were and not need to start at the top. I have been told using ajax is too complicated due to how new I am so i wanted to use redirect_to and anchor and just make the ID the story that was liked or disliked. Long story short, after reading every stackoverflow on this topic I still have no idea how to do it. I know I am close but think I need some help.

AFter more searching I have tried to convert from an anchor to using ajax so the page does not need to reload everytime someone clicks like or dislike. I have read many stackoverflows that are similar to mine, [How to add an anchor to redirect_to :back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793736/how-to-add-an-anchor-to-redirect-to-back), this one seems to be most simliar however i am still having problems.This is what I have:

Stories Controller

```
def upvote
  @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  @story.upvote_by(current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end

def downvote
  @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  @story.downvote_by(current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

_story.html.erb

```
<div class="story_partial" id="story_<%= story.id %>">
  <%= story.content %>
  <div id="downvote_button_<%= story.id %>">
    <%= link_to "dislike", downvote_path, method: "post", remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="story_partial" id="story_<%= story.id %>">
  <%= story.content %>
  <div id="upvote_button_<%= story.id %>">
    <%= link_to "like", upvote_path, method: "post", remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

upvote.js.erb

```
$('#story_<%= @story.id %>').html('<%= j render @story %>');
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to like_story_path(story), method: :post, remote: true, class: "btn btn-warning btn-xs" do %>
That scared me! <span class="text-warning"> </span>  <% end %>(<%= story.get_upvotes.size %>)
```

#I know these two buttons are different. I was trying to find the best way to make them work but neither automatically update. I need to refresh the page to have the counters update

```
<%= button_to dislike_story_path(story), method: :get, remote: true, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs" do %>
You Wimp! <span class="text-warning"></span><% end %>
(<%= story.get_downvotes.size %>)
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :stories do
   member do
    post :like, to:'stories#upvote'
    get :dislike, to:'stories#downvote'
  end
end
```

The buttons do work once I refresh the page however I am looking to get the like/dislike button to auto update once you click either like/dislike

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Isn't this one the exact answer you need ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757891/how-to-create-an-anchor-and-redirect-to-this-specific-anchor-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @Cailou, I have tried changing this to match what I need but i get a syntax error. I changed it to: <%= link_to post_path(@story.post) + "#story_#{@story.id.to_s}" %>

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: /home/ubuntu/workspace/scareme/app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting keyword_end <%= link_to post_path(@story.post) + "#story_#{@story.id.to_s}" %> ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/scareme/app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:40: unterminated string meets end of file /home/ubuntu/workspace/scareme/app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: Can you post **stories_controller.rb line 40**

Comment: @Abhi, I just updated my stories controller to what I hope is a closer solution

Comment: The "post_path" method gets you the path to the Post index, and you want the Story index. So you need to use story_path instead. `<%= link_to story_path(@story) + "#story_#{@story.id}" %>`

Comment: @PBukuras You were trying to use **View** code inside **Controller** because of which you got syntax error. You can also do `redirect_to post_path(@story.post, :anchor => 'contact')` [REFERRENCE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17884115/2968762)

Comment: @Caillou, I have changed the post to what you mentioned and have now received a syntax error. Looking at syntax errors I need to "end the string?" I tried putting end and <% end%> but it did not fix the problem

Comment: yes, i'm sorry i forgot the "visible text of the link" piece. But you should have seen it from the post I originaly linked : `<%= link_to "Index of stories", story_path(@story) + "#story_#{@story.id}" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's syntax for the link you should need :

```
<%= link_to "Blahblahblah this is a link", story_path(@story) + "#story_#{@story.id}" %>
```

Comment: Thanks Caillou, I am still getting the same SyntaxError with this "Index of stories" addition. just thinking, would the link_to do the same as a redirect_to since im looking for when people click the "like" button, it will just add a +1 to the like counter then they can continue scrolling to read posts. I just want to make sure im explaining what i am looking for

Comment: Nope, `link_to` is to create a link in your view file, and `redirect_to` is to redirect to a given adress in your controller file. So the `link_to` that I gave you is to be written in your view in order to create a link that will load the "index of stories" page, and go to the "story_x" anchor.

Comment: If you want people to be able to continue browsing your page after clicking a button, what you need is an Ajax request in javascript, which can send a post request whithout reloading the page.

Comment: Actually, all what you're telling me is quite confusing, maybe you should clarify your main post...